# Formating fixed presicion decimals in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I've been trying to do decimal to string conversion in RPG for a fixed precision decimal, and I could not find a BIF to handle the task. The precise output format I wanted in this case is left aligned without leading or trailing zeros:

```
0010.010 -> '10.01     '
```

Of course, I know how to do that myself with string manipulations, that's not the point. This problem has to have an easy built in solution. To put it in some code:

```
Dnum              S              7S03             
Ds                S             10A               
 /free                                            
   num = 010.010;                                 
   s = %char(num);                                
   dsply s ;                                      
 /end-free
```

This gives `'10.010    '`. I want `'10.01     '`. `%char` has an optional parameter `format`, to which [IBM](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/c092508429.htm#HDRBBCHAR) helpfully tells you, that it is used for date and time values.

I tried messing around with `%editc` and `%editw`, but without much success. Somehow the editword-syntax for `%editw` refuses to be understandable to me (and even google refuses to believe I want to use that BIF, it keeps telling me that what I really wanted is to search for `%editc`). If I get `%editw` to compile at all, I could not even convince it, to add the decimal point.

I tried `%editc` with the formats 'A' - 'D', 'J' - 'Q', 'X' - 'Z', '1' - '9'.
8 and 9 don't compile, and neither of the others gives me, what I want.

To be clear. I don't want to write my own function that does that. I don't want to call a C-function, like `sprintf`, I'm looking for a simple RPGLE solution. If there is none - well then not, but I'd like to know. It seems a simple enough task to be inside a report generation language.

Comment: How should the following display? 0.010 & 0.100  & .104 & .105

Comment: @Charles in my case: `0.01`, `0.1`, `0.104`, `0.105` all without any spaces before the first digit.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
   num = 010.010;                                 
   s = %trimr(%char(num):'0');                                
   dsply s ;
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend Charles' solution, if you need 9999.000 to look like 9,999 (i.e. you need the comma) then you will need an edit code.

```
num = 9999.000;
s = %trimr(%trim(%trim(%editc(num: 'B')):'0':'.');
dsply s;
```